# How to allow a user to customize keyboard shortcut keys?

Tags: macos, swiftui

In Xcode 12, you can add keyboard shortcuts with the `keyboardShortcut` modifier.

The key is a `KeyEquivalent`, so what's the best way to let users customize the shortcut when using SwiftUI?

How to create an application-specific keyboard shortcut through a Custom UI in the application. This shortcut is only active when the application is open, not a global hotkey.

```
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        print(">>> Button Triggered")
    }) {
        Text("Sample Label")
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("a", modifiers: [])
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/KeyboardShortcuts

Comment: Is the link to KeyboardShortcuts an answer to your question (i.e. how to create a custom UI for this?) Or is there more to your question? Note that while it can be nice to give users a custom UI if mapping keys is an important part of your app experience, users can always configure their own per-app shortcuts through System Settings: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac

Comment: KeyboardShortcuts framework is very good but it‘s **global** hotkeys. You‘d have to activate them according to your app activity.